# jQuery disable Scroll function when small screen size

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code snippet which uses the `scrollTop` function. Now I want to disable it on smaller screens. So this is my code:

```
jQuery(document).on("scroll",function(){
    if(jQuery(document).scrollTop()>100){
        jQuery("header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
        jQuery(".wrapper").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
        jQuery( ".site-navigation" ).fadeOut(100);
        jQuery(".mobile-navigation").fadeIn(100);
    }
    else{
        jQuery("header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
        jQuery(".wrapper").removeClass("small");
        jQuery( ".site-navigation" ).fadeIn(100);
        jQuery(".mobile-navigation").hide();
    }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".mobile-navigation").hide();
    jQuery("#hamburger").click(function(){
        jQuery( ".site-navigation" ).fadeIn(100);
        jQuery(".mobile-navigation").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
});
```

I've tried something with window.resize but I'm not sure where to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Just in case someone finds this post. Use a 
var limiter = 768; 
And add this if function: 
if ( $(window).width() > limiter ) { }